# How do I save a LibreOffice Calc file for opening in Excel?

Tags: libreoffice, file-format

I am trying to save a file in LibreOffice Calc that is still usable in Microsoft Office Excel. Save as `.xlms` doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `.xlms`? I don't see that as a `Save As` option in LibreOffice 3.6.

Answer (score 7):

`Menu>File>Save As` type ".xls".

Comment: OP specified `.xlms` not `.xls`. Unless that's a typo!

Answer (score 3):

Open your spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc.  Navigate to `File -> Save As`.

Make sure you open the "File Type" menu:

[image]

Then either select `.xls` or `.xlsx` depending on whether the version of Excel you are using is 2007 or newer:

[image]
Click "Save" and there you go.